# Django do something with each different value in a model field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I know I've seen this before, but I can't find now that I am ready to implement it.

I'm trying to list items on a page by category and subcategory, but I only want 1 category and then the subcategories in the category. Hopefully my code will make sense.

```
class Objects(models.Model):
    # Main Checkbox.
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
    )
    # Checkboxes under Main Checkbox.
    subcategory = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
    )
```

So my objects are stored as:

```
category1, subcategory1
category1, subcategory2
category2, subcategory1
category2, subcategory2
```

And when displayed should give me:

```
category1
    subcategory1
    subcategory2
category2
    subcategory1
    subcategory2
```

How do I set my query so that my results show me each "different" `category`?

Comment: It looks like introducing a lot of data duplication. Typically this is resolved by *normalizing* the database by creating a `Category` model, and thus use `ForeignKey`s to the `Category`, instead of writing the `Category` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you should look to normalise your objects, meaning you could keep your subcategories as a separate object and use `models.foreignKey` to link them together. See [Willem Van Onsem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52457745/10400050) for this.

However, to solve the current problem you should be able to utilize the [regroup template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) in order to aggregate the categories.

In your case it would look something like:

```
{% regroup objects by category as categories %}
{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category.grouper }}
    {% for subcategory in category.list %}
        {{ subcategory }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

## The *data duplication* anti-pattern

Many computer scientists see this as bad design, since it introduces *data duplication*. Imagine that you later want to change the name of a category, then that means you need to find *all* occurrences of that category, and rename them. If you only use this for the `Object`s model, then that is perhaps doable, but if all sorts of elements belong to `Category`s, then this easily gets out of hand.

Furthermore it also restricts categories: two *different* categories can never have the same name (which might here be reasonable), nor can we attach much properties to the `Category`: imagine that we want to add a `description` for the category, then that description needs to be repeated over all rows, or if we decide to store it only in *one* row, then it will be hard to find that specific row. Furthermore if there are two rows with different descriptions, then what description to pick?

The database will also be very huge: each row should repeat the same category. If a category on average takes 15 characters, that means that we will - depending on the encoding - easily waste 8 bytes per row (well the row contains 16 bytes for a string given it is UTF-8 encoding, and only ASCII characters, but a `ForeignKey` will frequently use 8 bytes). If we would add a description that has on average 63 characters, then we would again waste another 64 bytes *per row*.  For a small amount of rows, that is not a problem, but the problem easily scales problematic. The above are of course only estimates on what problems might arise, do not see this as the "real numbers": the size a database takes is determined by a lot of parameters that are here either ignored, or estimated.

Yes all these problems probably can be solved, but instead of solving the problems *ad-hoc*, it is better to normalize the database.

## Normalizing the models

Normalization typically means that we introduce extra tables that store for example *one* record per `Category`, and use `ForeignKey`s to refer to that record. For you example a normalized variant would be:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Object(models.Model):
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        SubCategory,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
```

So we store `Category`s and `SubCategory`s in dedicated tables, and link the models together with `ForeignKey`s.

## Rendering lists of (`Sub`)`Category`s

Now that we normalized the models, we can effectively render the `Category`s with:

```
# app/views.py

def some_view(request):
    categories = Category.objects.prefetch_related('subcategory_set')
    return render(request, 'app/some_template.html', {'categories': categories})
```

and in the `app/templates/some_template.html` we then can render it as:

```
<ul>
{% for cat in categories %}
    <li>{{ cat.name }}</li>
    <ul>
    {% for subcat in cat.subcategory_set %}
    <li>{{ subcat.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

We thus iterate over all `categories`, and for every `cat`, we iterate over the `subcategory_set`.

Comment: I agree with you about the duplication. What I am trying to do is a "special case". The `{% regroup %}` tag is what I was looking for.